How am I able to not have my data come in when I convert to data frame for my code within R Time series analysis?
I am looking to create a code that brings in data from a csv file that is pasted below. I am trying to have all of the commodities compare to the MOM change to the inflation rate with diesel in all of the charts as well. Then measure the correlation between them to see if inflation is correlated to them.

Below is the code
# Load necessary libraries library(readr) library(dplyr) library(ggplot2)
# Read the data from the CSV file
data <- read_csv("commodities_inflation_data.csv", skip = 1)  # Skip the first row (header row)

# Extract the date columns from the header row
dates <- as.Date(names(data)[-1], format = "MOM %b %Y")

# Transpose the data so that commodities are in rows and dates are in columns
data <- t(data[-1])  # Transpose the data excluding the first column

# Convert to data frame
data <- as.data.frame(data, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
names(data) <- c("Commodity", dates)  # Rename columns

# Define the commodities of interest
commodities_of_interest <- c("Wheat", "Soybean", "Corn", "Ground_Beef", "Bacon", "Eggs",     "Chicken")

# Plot each commodity against inflation and diesel separately
for (commodity in commodities_of_interest) {
  p1 <- ggplot(data, aes(x = dates, y = !!sym(commodity))) +
geom_line(color = "blue") +
    geom_line(aes(y = Inflation), color = "red") +
    labs(title = paste("Monthly Percentage Change in", commodity, "vs. Inflation"),
     y = "Percentage Change",
     x = "Date") +
    theme_minimal()
  print(p1)

  p2 <- ggplot(data, aes(x = dates, y = !!sym(commodity))) +
    geom_line(color = "blue") +
    geom_line(aes(y = Diesel), color = "green") +
    labs(title = paste("Monthly Percentage Change in", commodity, "vs. Diesel"),
         y = "Percentage Change",
         x = "Date") +
    theme_minimal()
  print(p2)
}

# Calculate correlation between inflation and commodities
correlation_with_inflation <- sapply(data[, commodities_of_interest], function(x) cor(x,             data$Inflation))

# Calculate correlation between inflation, diesel, and commodities
correlation_with_inflation_and_diesel <- sapply(data[, commodities_of_interest], function(x)     cor(x,     cbind(data$Inflation, data$Diesel)))

# Print correlation results
print("Correlation between inflation and commodities:")
print(correlation_with_inflation)

print("Correlation between inflation, diesel, and commodities:")
print(correlation_with_inflation_and_diesel)`

> # Load necessary libraries
> library(readr)
> library(dplyr)

Attaching package: ‘dplyr’

The following objects are masked from ‘package:stats’:

    filter, lag

The following objects are masked from ‘package:base’:

    intersect, setdiff, setequal, union

> library(ggplot2)
> # Read the data from the CSV file
> data <- read.csv("commodities_inflation_data.csv", skip = 1)  # Skip the first row (header row)
> # Extract the date columns from the header row
> dates <- as.Date(names(data)[-1], format = "MOM %b %Y")
> # Transpose the data so that commodities are in rows and dates are in columns
> data <- t(data[-1])  # Transpose the data excluding the first column
> # Convert to data frame
> data <- as.data.frame(data, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
> names(data) <- c("Commodity", dates)  # Rename columns
Error in names(data) <- c("Commodity", dates) : 
  'names' attribute [39] must be the same length as the vector [8]
> # Define the commodities of interest
> commodities_of_interest <- c("Wheat", "Soybean", "Corn", "Ground_Beef", "Bacon", "Eggs", "Chicken")
> # Plot each commodity against inflation and diesel separately
> for (commodity in commodities_of_interest) {
+   p1 <- ggplot(data, aes(x = dates, y = !!sym(commodity))) +
+     geom_line(color = "blue") +
+     geom_line(aes(y = Inflation), color = "red") +
+     labs(title = paste("Monthly Percentage Change in", commodity, "vs. Inflation"),
+          y = "Percentage Change",
+          x = "Date") +
+     theme_minimal()
+   print(p1)
+   
+   p2 <- ggplot(data, aes(x = dates, y = !!sym(commodity))) +
+     geom_line(color = "blue") +
+     geom_line(aes(y = Diesel), color = "green") +
+     labs(title = paste("Monthly Percentage Change in", commodity, "vs. Diesel"),
+          y = "Percentage Change",
+          x = "Date") +
+     theme_minimal()
+   print(p2)
+ }
Error in `geom_line()`:
! Problem while computing aesthetics.
ℹ Error occurred in the 1st layer.
Caused by error in `FUN()`:
! object 'Wheat' not found
Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see where the error occurred.
> # Calculate correlation between inflation and commodities
> correlation_with_inflation <- sapply(data[, commodities_of_interest], function(x) cor(x, data$Inflation))
Error in `[.data.frame`(data, , commodities_of_interest) : 
  undefined columns selected
> # Calculate correlation between inflation, diesel, and commodities
> correlation_with_inflation_and_diesel <- sapply(data[, commodities_of_interest], function(x) cor(x, cbind(data$Inflation, data$Diesel)))
Error in `[.data.frame`(data, , commodities_of_interest) : 
  undefined columns selected
> # Print correlation results
> print("Correlation between inflation and commodities:")
[1] "Correlation between inflation and commodities:"
> print(correlation_with_inflation)
Error in print(correlation_with_inflation) : 
  object 'correlation_with_inflation' not found
> print("Correlation between inflation, diesel, and commodities:")
[1] "Correlation between inflation, diesel, and commodities:"
> print(correlation_with_inflation_and_diesel)
Error in print(correlation_with_inflation_and_diesel) : 
  object 'correlation_with_inflation_and_diesel' not found


This question is very long. It looks like you run into an error at the names(data) step  which cascades into your other errors. In that step you have a mismatch between the number of columns and the number of new names you want to give them.

Read [ask] and then [edit] your question to narrow the focus.

Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a minimal reproducible example.
